# Download all the derivatives for the purpose of the using Forge Viewer offline/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

refering to this post ,I know there is a way to download the tranlated files with node.js" 
[How do I download SVG/SVF for offline viewing with Autodesk Model Forge APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009930/how-do-i-download-svg-svf-for-offline-viewing-with-autodesk-model-forge-apis)",and using the Model Derivative api "GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn", I can download all the files record in manifest,
download files pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAdgf.jpg

my question is :are these files I download from manifest with "GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn"  enough for offline viewing? If not,did anyone implement this download method with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are enough, the manifest allows you to download every resource from a viewable package. As already pointed out in the answer you can find more information and full code sample from the https://extract.autodesk.io project.

We don't have a .Net version of that code at the moment.